# How do I write HTML in a document and have it be displayed as plain text but also be able to be copied via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small page I am building where I want to be able to put in code snippets that I can later copy out using a JavaScript function. The function is working great but I am running into issues when I try to use XML, HTML, or other similar languages.

When I try to use these languages my first instinct is replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively. The issue is, when I have my JavaScript function copy the snippet to the clipboard, it also copies the `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead of the `<` `>` that are displayed on the page.

Is there a way I can type out my code, as is, and have it be displayed in its entirety in the document so that my JavaScript can also copy it?

I've seen people use `<pre>` and `<code>` but they honestly don't seem to be making a difference:

```
<pre>
    <code>
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
            <url>
                <loc>https://www.example.com/home.html/</loc>
                <lastmod>2020-04-21</lastmod>
                <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
                <priority>1.0</priority>
            </url>
        </urlset>
    </code>
</pre>
```

Is still displaying on my page as:

```
        https://www.example.com/home.html/
        2020-04-21
        monthly
        1.0
```

And also just straight up breaking my JavaScript copy function -

Working Example:

```
<h2>.htaccess</h2>
    <div class="group">
        <h3 class="head">Snippet Header</h3>
        <div onclick="copyClipboard(1,1)">
            <p>code</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
function copyClipboard(oldNum,oldGroup) {
var codeNum = (oldNum - 1);
var groupNum = (oldGroup - 1);
var codeBox = document.getElementsByClassName("group")[groupNum].querySelectorAll("div");
var codeP = document.getElementsByClassName("group")[groupNum].querySelectorAll("p");
var temp_input = document.createElement("textarea");
document.body.appendChild(temp_input);
temp_input.value = codeP[codeNum].innerHTML;
temp_input.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
document.body.removeChild(temp_input);
};
```

*(I am using 'groupNum' for an animation later in the code)*

Does anyone know how I could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you should convert special characters to HTML-entities.
To copy it as rendered, copy the `textContent` of your element instead of its `innerHTML`.

```js
function copyClipboard(oldNum, oldGroup) {
  var codeNum = (oldNum - 1);
  var groupNum = (oldGroup - 1);
  var codeBox = document.getElementsByClassName("group")[groupNum].querySelectorAll("div");
  var codeP = document.getElementsByClassName("group")[groupNum].querySelectorAll("pre");
  var temp_input = document.createElement("textarea");
  document.body.appendChild(temp_input);
  // copy the textContent
  temp_input.value = codeP[codeNum].textContent;
  temp_input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(temp_input);
};
```

```html
<h2>.htaccess</h2>
<div class="group">
  <h3 class="head">Snippet Header</h3>
  <p>click following code to copy to clipboard</p>
  <div onclick="copyClipboard(1,1)">
    <pre>
&lt;urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"&gt; 
  &lt;url&gt;
    &lt;loc&gt;https://www.example.com/home.html/&lt;/loc&gt;
    &lt;lastmod&gt;2020-04-21&lt;/lastmod&gt;
    &lt;changefreq&gt;monthly&lt;/changefreq&gt;
    &lt;priority&gt;1.0&lt;/priority&gt;
  &lt;/url&gt;
&lt;/urlset&gt;
</pre>
  </div>
</div>
<textarea rows="10" cols="70" placeholder="paste here"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a textarea:

```html
<textarea disabled rows=10 cols=70>
  <urlset xmlns="https://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> 
      <url>
          <loc>https://www.example.com/home.html/</loc>
          <lastmod>2020-04-21</lastmod>
          <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
          <priority>1.0</priority>
      </url>
  </urlset>
</textarea>
```

To get its value, use `document.querySelector('textarea').value`.

To prevent the user from being able to alter it, add the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: You'd still have to escape `</textarea>`.